# Simple switch for pneumatic cylinder

Tags: design, controller

I am an automotive machinist and not at all electronics inclined.
I simply need a switch that turns on and off for a 5 port 2 position pneumatic solenoid valve

I simply need the pneumatic cylinder it controls to reverse directions at a steady rate.

It’s for a cylinder honing machine.

Step on the pedal and the power head energizes. I have one 110 circuit available that turns on and off with the head I could easily plug a 12 volt adapter into.

I have 2 reed switch’s on the pneumatic cylinder for setting top and bottom of stroke. I simply adjust them up or down to the desired position   Cylinder will never go full in or out. Just alternating between the magnetic reed switches located somewhere between the top half and bottom half of the pneumatic cylinder depending on the length of engine cylinder Im honing at that time.

I need the switch that takes the signal from the reed switches and alternates between on and off to the solenoid valve so the machine continuously strokes up and down.

If I have 12 volts to my valve it is open and cylinder extends
turn off 12 volts cylinder retracts.

Switches are 12 volt
Solenoid is 12 volt

My ignorance will require very simple instructions.
Willing to buy a simple custom built controller from someone too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post photos of the "5 port 2 position pneumatic solenoid valve" so we can see what we are dealing with.  Assume we know as much about multi-port multi-position solenoid valves as you do about electronics.

Comment: Reed switches can't switch enough current to drive solenoids, so you'd need low-current relays or (even better) some kind of controller to read the reed's as inputs and drive the valves as outputs. It's been a long time since I've sourced hobby-grade PLC's, but perhaps someone here can chime it...

Answer (score 0):

Could you  not just install with a mag base a simple limit switch it is basic open closed with it being attached to a mag base you would be able to adjust it to any stroke you desired granger has them

Answer (score 0):

A latching relay with separate set and reset coils is probably the easiest solution here. Have the bottom limit switch pulse the set coil and the top limit switch pulse the reset coil. Connect the valve solenoid to the normally open switched contacts.